# How to send selected option to spring controller on spring form submission

Tags: jquery, spring, jquery-ui, spring-mvc

Sample Code

```
<form name='add'>
Age: <select name='age'>
     <option value='1' stud_name='sre'>23</option>
     <option value='2' stud_name='sam'>24</option>
     <option value='5' stud_name='john'>25</option>
     </select>
<input type='submit' name='submit'/>
</form>
```

If I **choose 23** from the dropdown, on Submission of the above form, instead of **value=1** , I should send 23 to the age parameter.

Can you please help?

Comment: Then change the value from 1 to 23... The value is what is send back to the server as it should. The other thing is just a label.

Comment: does it need to be `1` as value?

Comment: show us the jquery code?

Comment: What has this to do with jquery or spring? It looks like plain HTML.

Comment: Thank You for the reply, i am using the value 1 on jquery event , based on the value i am caliculating some other.

Comment: for ref i added the html code.... but all are spring related tags

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=submit]').on('click', function() {
    alert('hi');
    var aa = $('#age option:selected').text();
    aa = $('#age option:selected').val(aa);
    console.log('value is' + aa);
  });
});
```

Use this. But I am still confused what you want to do actually.

Answer (score 0):

Change value attribute to proper value. If you need to keep additional value in your option tag you can use data-attribute:

```
<form name='add'>
Age: <select name='age'>
     <option value='23' data-custom-value="1" stud_name='sre'>23</option>
     <option value='24' data-custom-value="2" stud_name='sam'>24</option>
     <option value='25' data-custom-value="5" stud_name='john'>25</option>
     </select>
<input type='submit' name='submit'/>
</form>
```

Access to that attribute in js:

```
//you need get optionElement first
optionElement.getAttribute('data-custom-value');
```

I think you can't make my solution work with spring security tags (itemLabel etc). There will be problems with the selected value. 
But you can try something like this:

```
<select name="age">
    <c:forEach var="item" items="${ages}">
        <option value="${age.value}" ${item.val== age.value ? 'selected="selected"' : ''}>${item.value}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```